# Solve for $x$ the equation $ x^{\log_{10} x}=\frac{x^3}{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve for $x$ the equation $x^{\log x}=\frac{x^3}{100}$, where $\log$ means $\log_{10}$.

What I tried:

> $$x^{\log x}=\dfrac{x^3}{100}$$
>   Taking $\log$ of both sides
>   $$\log{x^{\log x}}=\log{\dfrac{x^3}{100}}$$
>   Using power rule on the left side
>   $$(\log x)^2=\log{\dfrac{x^3}{100}}$$
>   Using properties of $\log$ and power rule on the right side
>   $$(\log x)^2=3\log{x}-\log{100}$$

Now I am stuck. I can bring all of the terms with $x$ over to one side, but I cannot factor out $x$ completely. How should I proceed?

Comment: Ever heard of quadratic equations?

Comment: Let me try it $\!$

Comment: OOps, simple mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

after we have $$(\log_{10} x)^2=3\log_{10} x-2$$ we can set $$t=\log_{10} x$$ and you have to solve this here
$$t^2-3t+2=0$$
can you finish this?

Comment: Nice job of scaffolding. Get's the OP to the next stage, but still allowing him/her to do some thinking.